# How to read multiple tables from different directory in R?

Tags: r

I have a list of files under 12 different folders, each file has the same name. For example, under folder_A  there is a file called quant.txt, under folder_B there is also a file called quant.txt, and so on for other folders. All of these 12 folders are under the same directory.

How do I read/import the list of files from those 12 folders? Maybe something like `lapply` or `list.files`?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the the read function but I'm just going to use `readLines` as a surrogate.

```
quantData <- purrr::map(list.dirs(), ~readLines(file.path(.x, "quant.txt"))
```

This iterates through your list of folders, reading the "quant.txt" from each